# UIAlerController Action Sheet does not respond the second time it's called

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I have something like the following code. The Action sheet runs doSomething OK when it appears for the first time (in a button IBAction), but when it appears the second time, nothing happens the Action sheet just disappear without calling do something. Any idea?

```
@implementation ...

- (void) setActions {
    UIAlertAction *opt1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            [self doSomething:@"opt1"];}];

    UIAlertAction *opt2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 2"    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            [self doSomething:@"opt2"];}];

    UIAlertAction *opt3 = ...

    self.opt1 = opt1;
    self.opt2 = opt2;
    self.opt3 = opt3;

- (void) showActionSheet {

    ...
UIAlertController *selectAS = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Options"
 message:@"msg" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    if (xyz) {                  
          [selectAS addAction:self.opt1];
          [selectAS addAction:self.opt2];
        }
    else{            
          [selectAS addAction:self.opt1];
          [selectAS addAction:self.opt3];                    
        }
   [self presentViewController:selectqAS 
    animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

- (void) doSomething: (NSString *) opt{



  ....
    }
```

Comment: Your syntax is extremely confusing to me. Image looking at your code a year from now, you yourself won't know whats going on. Apple introduced the UIAlertController because it includes completion handlers in a more robust elegant manner as opposed to its counterpart. You should utilize it that way instead of having different methods for everything. This can all be done in one code snippet. Just create/customize/and present the UIAlertController inside the IBAction

Comment: For reasons beyond me, your suggestion worked. Same code all inside the IBAction was OK. Thanks (you can actually post it as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad we got you up and running. My guess is your methods are getting lost in translation. You have methods intertwining each other which can be causing the confusion, specifically with `self.opt1`. per my comment, now that iOS8 has introduced `UIAlertController`, it comes with completion handlers, you should plan accordingly to that: something like the following :

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet {
    UIAlertController *selectAS = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Options" message:@"msg" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

     UIAlertAction *opt1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //Don't have to call another method, just put your action 1 code here. This is the power of completion handlers creating a more structured outline
     }];

     UIAlertAction *opt2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //Don't have to call another method, just put your action 2 code here. This is the power of completion handlers creating a more structured outline
     }];

     UIAlertAction *opt3 = ...

     if (xyz) {
       [selectAs addAction:opt1];
       [selectAs addAction:opt2];
     } else {
       [selectAs addAction:opt1];
       [selectAs addAction:opt3];
     }        

     [self presentViewController:selectAs animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

Much more cleaner and actually uses the UIAlertController for it's intended purposes, no other method calls needed.